# ext.net mvc gridpanel using datasource with complex model type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net, gridpanel

I am having trouble getting a partial view working. The partial view has a gridpanel embedded in it along with some other text boxes. I have a custom model class with some string properties to fill the text boxes and a list of custom objects to populate the grid. I am using .DataSource(Model.MyList) to populate the gridpanel, but I keep getting a null reference exception - object not set to an instance of an object. If I remove the datasource line, it renders correctly (obviously without any data in the grid) - the other fields are correctly populated.

Here is some sample code -

```
@(x.FormPanel()
    .ID("MyDetailsPanel")
    .Title("My Details")
        .Frame(true)
        .Height(525)
        .Width(425)
        .Margin(5)        
        .Items(
            x.TextFieldFor(m => m.Title)
                .FieldLabel("Title")
                .AnchorHorizontal("100%"),
            x.TextField()
                .FieldLabel("Number")
                .AnchorHorizontal("100%"),
            x.ComboBox()
                .FieldLabel("Type")
                .AnchorHorizontal("100%"),


                x.GridPanel()
                    .Title("My Grid")
                    .Frame(true)
                    .Width(400)
                    .Height(350)
                    .Store(
                        x.Store()
                            .AutoLoad(true)
                            .ID("MyStore")
                            .DataSource(Model.MyList)
                            .Model(
                                x.Model()
                                    .Fields(
                                        x.ModelField().Name("Number").Type(ModelFieldType.String),
                                        x.ModelField().Name("Title").Type(ModelFieldType.String)
                                    )
......
```

Here is the model -

```
public class MyDetailsViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public  List<SomeDto> MyList { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the controller -

```
public ActionResult MyDetailsPartial(string id)
        {
            var vm = new MyDetailsViewModel();
            vm.MyList = new List<SomeDto>();
            if(id != null)
            {
                vm.Title = "new title";
                vm.MyList.Add(new SomeDto { Number = "234", Title = "abcd"});
            }            

            ViewData.Model = vm;

            var pvr = new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewData = this.ViewData

            };
            return pvr;         
        }
```

I can't understand why I can't pass a custom list from the model into the datasource for the gridpanel.

Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using GridPanelFor.  By using this, the view renders and updates as expected.

Thanks